# cannot winros_make

Tags: windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, this is what I get when I try to compile my workspace. I sense that it is something simple but can't quite figure it out. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
 C:\work\ws>winros_make -p
--- cleaning current cmake and build temporaries (not the build configuration).

Executing cmake on the workspace source directory:

  cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -C "C:\work\ws\config.cmake" -DCMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE:STRING="C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win_ros\cmake\MsvcOverrides.cmake" -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=C:\work\ws\devel C:\work\ws\src

loading initial cache file C:\work\ws\config.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: C:/work/ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: C:/opt/rosdeps/hydro/x86
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python27/python.exe (found version "2.7.2")
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: C:/Python27/python.exe
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Found PY_em: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\em.pyc
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: C:/work/ws/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found gtest sources under 'C:/work/ws/src/gtest': gtests will be built
CMake Warning at catkin/cmake/test/nosetests.cmake:94 (message):
  nosetests not found, Python tests can not be run (try installing package
  'python-nose')
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/all.cmake:138 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (include)


-- catkin 0.5.78
-- skipping nosetests(test/local_tests) in project 'catkin'
-- skipping nosetests(test/unit_tests) in project 'catkin'
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 81 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - common_msgs (metapackage)
-- ~~  - cpp_common
-- ~~  - genmsg
-- ~~  - gencpp
-- ~~  - genlisp
-- ~~  - genpy
-- ~~  - message_generation
-- ~~  - message_runtime
-- ~~  - mingw_cross
-- ~~  - mk
-- ~~  - ros (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros_comm (metapackage)
-- ~~  - rosbash
-- ~~  - rosboost_cfg
-- ~~  - rosbuild
-- ~~  - rosclean
-- ~~  - roscpp_core (metapackage)
-- ~~  - roscpp_traits
-- ~~  - roscreate
-- ~~  - rosgraph
-- ~~  - roslang
-- ~~  - roslaunch
-- ~~  - rosmake
-- ~~  - rosmaster
-- ~~  - rosmsg
-- ~~  - rospack
-- ~~  - roslib
-- ~~  - rosparam
-- ~~  - rospy
-- ~~  - rosrun
-- ~~  - rosservice
-- ~~  - rostime
-- ~~  - roscpp_serialization
-- ~~  - rosunit
-- ~~  - rosconsole
-- ~~  - rostest
-- ~~  - std_msgs
-- ~~  - actionlib_msgs
-- ~~  - diagnostic_msgs
-- ~~  - geometry_msgs
-- ~~  - nav_msgs
-- ~~  - rosgraph_msgs
-- ~~  - sensor_msgs
-- ~~  - shape_msgs
-- ~~  - std_srvs
-- ~~  - stereo_msgs
-- ~~  - test_roslib_comm
-- ~~  - trajectory_msgs
-- ~~  - visualization_msgs
-- ~~  - win_boost
-- ~~  - win_bzip2
-- ~~  - win_dateutil
-- ~~  - win_eigen
-- ~~  - win_empy
-- ~~  - win_mercurial
-- ~~  - win_pyyaml
-- ~~  - win_python_build_tools
-- ~~  - win_ros (metapackage)
-- ~~  - win_tinyxml
-- ~~  - winros_create_msg_pkg
-- ~~  - winros_create_pkg
-- ~~  - xmlrpcpp
-- ~~  - roscpp
-- ~~  - rosout
-- ~~  - actionlib
-- ~~  - message_filters
-- ~~  - rosnode
-- ~~  - rostopic
-- ~~  - roswtf
-- ~~  - test_roscpp
-- ~~  - test_rosgraph
-- ~~  - test_roslaunch
-- ~~  - test_rosmaster
-- ~~  - test_rosparam
-- ~~  - test_rospy
-- ~~  - test_rosservice
-- ~~  - topic_tools
-- ~~  - rosbag
-- ~~  - test_rosbag
-- ~~  - win_roscpp_tutorials
-- ~~  - msvc_runtime
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'common_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(common_msgs/common_msgs)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'cpp_common'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(roscpp_core/cpp_common)
-- Looking for execinfo.h
-- Looking for execinfo.h - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXXABI_H
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXXABI_H - Failed
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - not found
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'genmsg'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(genmsg)
-- skipping nosetests(test) in project 'genmsg'
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'gencpp'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(gencpp)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'genlisp'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(genlisp)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'genpy'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(genpy)
-- skipping nosetests(test) in project 'genpy'
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'message_generation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(message_generation)
WARNING: 'catkin' should be listed as a buildtool dependency in the package.xml
(instead of build dependency)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'message_runtime'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(message_runtime)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'mingw_cross'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(win_ros/mingw/mingw_cross)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'mk'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/core/mk)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'ros'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/ros)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'ros_comm'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/ros_comm)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosbash'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/tools/rosbash)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosboost_cfg'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/tools/rosboost_cfg)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosbuild'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/core/rosbuild)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosclean'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/tools/rosclean)
-- skipping nosetests(test) in project 'rosclean'
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'roscpp_core'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(roscpp_core/roscpp_core)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'roscpp_traits'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(roscpp_core/roscpp_traits)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'roscreate'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/tools/roscreate)
-- skipping nosetests(test) in project 'roscreate'
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosgraph'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/tools/rosgraph)
-- skipping nosetests(test) in project 'rosgraph'
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'roslang'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/core/roslang)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'roslaunch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/tools/roslaunch)
-- skipping nosetests(test/unit) in project 'roslaunch'
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosmake'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros/tools/rosmake)
-- skipping nosetests(test) in project 'rosmake'
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosmaster'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/tools/rosmaster)
-- skipping nosetests(test) in project 'rosmaster'
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosmsg'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/tools/rosmsg)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rospack'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rospack)
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   system
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:291 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:186 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  rospack/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Executing nmake in the root build directory


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop.
```

- I have win8.1 and ros hydro(x64).I am using the tutorials on the site and mosly this one:
  http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc%20Overlays

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212658/cannot-winros_make/) by [Morgane](https://answers.ros.org/users/21508/morgane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-01**:
From the output I'd say it cannot find your Python development libs.

We don't know what version of Windows you are trying this on, so please add that, as well as what tutorials / documentation you are following.

**Comment by [Morgane](https://answers.ros.org/users/21508/morgane/) on 2015-07-01**:
Edited to add the required info. i am currently reinstalling visual studio in case I have the problem that is caused by the sdk...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-01**:
Windows 8.1 is tricky. There are some posts on the [win-ros](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/win-ros) google group about that. You might want to check there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem. My machine and winros are (x64) build but Python is (x86)  so after a lot of tempering around registry and reinstalling things I finally found the solution: I just downloaded python 2.7.2 (x86x64).

---

Originally posted by [Morgane](https://answers.ros.org/users/21508/morgane/) with karma: 41 on 2015-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0